# Systemd service does not save changes to disk

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, echo, tee, systemctl

Wrote a simple `keychron.service` file to overwrite a parameter during each boot-up.

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Description=The command to make the Keychron K2 work                            
                                                                            
[Service]                                                                       
Type=oneshot                                                                    
ExecStart=/bin/echo 0 | sudo /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
                                                                               
[Install]                                                                       
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This script is for patching my keyboard, and it simply writes a `0` into `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. Here's what I did in an attempt to troubleshoot it.

1. Check that `fnmode` is `1`

```
thekenu:~
$ cat /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
1
```

2. Restart `keychron.service`, and use `systemctl status` to ensure it restarted successfully

```
thekenu:~
$ sudo systemctl restart keychron.service
thekenu:~
$ systemctl status keychron.service
● keychron.service - The command to make the Keychron K2 work
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/keychron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2020-07-22 06:33:13 PDT; 3s ago
  Process: 28778 ExecStart=/bin/echo 0 | sudo /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28778 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 22 06:33:13 thekenu-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Starting The command to make the Keychron K2 work...
Jul 22 06:33:13 thekenu-XPS-15-9560 echo[28778]: 0 | sudo /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
Jul 22 06:33:13 thekenu-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Started The command to make the Keychron K2 work.
```

3. Expected `fnmode` to be `0`, but it is still `1`

```
thekenu:~
$ cat /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
1
```

4. Run the `ExecStart` command from `keychron.service`

```
thekenu:~
$ /bin/echo 0 | sudo /usr/bin/tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
0
```

5. Now `fnmode` is `0`. But it seems like I merely typed out what `keychrone.service` was supposed to do.

```
thekenu:~
$ cat /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecStart` is not a normal shell line. From `systemd.service(5)`:

> ExecStart=
>
> Commands with their arguments that are executed when this service is started. The value is split into zero or more command lines according to the rules  described below (see section "Command Lines" below).

You're operating a system unit, not a user unit, so you're already `root` and don't need to complicate the `Exec` with `sudo`:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the redundant `sudo`. However, I believe the main thing I was missing is pointed out by this `man systemd.service` snippet:`Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.`

Once I realized this, I was able to search for similar problems on StackExchange a lot easier. It turns out this is a common problem too. In any case, thanks for the help!